# How to tell which resources are loaded "insecurely" with Chrome using https

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I understand this is because I'm loading some stuff via `http://` but does that mean a single http reference can't appear in the source? Even in examples like `<a href="http://...">...</a>`?

How can I find specially which resources are causing the problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936196/google-chrome-how-to-see-the-css-files-loaded-in-a-page) which describes how to see a list all resources.  It includes the URL, which you can inspect to see if is http instead of https.

Comment: Absolutely, it's invaluable.  When I got bitten, it turned out to be that my securely loaded CSS was using Google Web Fonts with an http: load to add a new font; changed that to an https and the problem was solved.  I'd never have tracked it down without the DevTools Resources panel.

Answer (score 2):

Hyperlinks do not load resources unless clicked. Typical culprits are usually images or frames loaded without the https prefix. I'd take a look through the source for http links for a better idea.