# How to find what elements on SSL page are insecure?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell which resources are loaded “insecurely” with Chrome using https](https://superuser.com/questions/232974/how-to-tell-which-resources-are-loaded-insecurely-with-chrome-using-https)

I"m using a major tax site for this year's taxes, and I am getting the "Some elements on this page are insecure" message in the URL bar in Chrome that seems to happen every now and then in gmail.

Is there a way to find out what parts are insecure? Is this even something to worry about?

Once I login, I get the green lock in the URL bar and is says that all elements are secure.

For reference, I'm getting the Yellow Triangle next to the lock (3rd one down), found on this page: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not the only tool or even the easiest for this problem, I always recommend to use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the entire network. Then you (painstakingly, I admit) examine each connection and see which ones are not going over SSL. With a little practice you'll learn to quickly filter out the traffic you are not interested in. Hint: Analyze -> "Follow TCP Stream" is pure gold.

You can also watch DNS in action and see other network goodies.